# XPath not expected result with lxml

Tags: python, xpath, lxml

I'm sorry if my question isn't formatted right, English isn't my native language.

I'm trying to get the table from the following url [Bulapedia, Bulbasaur](https://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Bulbasaur_(Pok%C3%A9mon)#Type_effectiveness) But lxml gives me very weird results when I use xpath.

I've tried the following:

```
for elem in tree.xpath('//*[@id="mw-content-text"]//table[14]//tr[3]//td//table//tr//td'):
    print(etree.tostring(elem, pretty_print=True))
```

This doesn't give me the data I need, it gives values from a different table data, randomized even.

I'm at a loss of what to try now, cssselect isn't an option either, since that seems to change depending on which Pokemon I'm searching for.

I'm trying to get the following results:
[image]

Comment: Tell us what you're trying to get.

Comment: @pguardiario I'm trying to get the following: https://i.imgur.com/FjvYxqW.png

Comment: use cssselect and do:  `th:contains("Weak to:") + td`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Other than the first element `*[@id="mw-content-text"]`, all the rest of the elements in your XPath should be the immediate children of the ones before them. By using `//` you're selecting elements of any depth within the parent, which is not what you want.

Change all but the first `//`s to `/` and it should work as intended:

```
for elem in tree.xpath('//*[@id="mw-content-text"]/table[14]/tr[3]/td/table/tr/td'):
    print(etree.tostring(elem, pretty_print=True))
```

Comment: I'm getting the exact same results :c

Comment: I figured it out with your example! Thank you!